# Time value added to dates when storing in MS Access

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, oledbcommand

I am using a .NET program to read data from a delimited text file and then add the data programmatically to an Access database (.mdb file). The program uses VB.Net with the .NET 3.5 Framework.

The routine doing the data adding uses a OleDbCommand with an `INSERT` statement such as:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (secID, dataDate, salary ) VALUES (@secID, @dataDate, @salary)
```

The OleDBCommand's parameter value corresponding to parameter `@dataDate` typically has a value such as `"25-Nov-2011 00:00"` (a string). [This is what I see if I debug and inspect the OleDBCommand right before a row is added to the database].

Generally, when the data is then inspected in Access, the dates appear WITHOUT a time value, like this: `"25/11/2011"`. This is the desired result.

However, with one computer, when the dates are added to MS Access, they have a time value added (they appear as: `"25/11/2011 12:00 p.m."`). I know how to fix this in Access (run dateValue query). My problem is I cannot figure out WHY this happens on only this one machine. It causes data query problems downstream on this computer.

The problem computer runs Windows 7 and has MS Access 2010 installed (although that is only relevant for inspecting the data, since we are using oleDBCommand from .NET - I think?). It is a corporate computer so security permissions etc are quite strict. Other computers tested (our own) have the same Windows and Access configuration but not the same issue.

We also checked that the regional date/time settings on all computers are the same. Only this one computer has the issue.

I have spend days on this, would really appreciate help from someone who encountered and solved this before! Many Thanks.

Comment: The column IS a dateTime column in access. The string value is just the parameter value that is passed to the OleDBProvider.

Comment: I *strongly* recommend that you do not use formats in tables, they merely disguise the contents of a field, they do not change the content. A field formatted as short date will still contain the tome element, it just will not be displayed, leading to all sorts of confusion.

Comment: Thanks Remou, I agree jwith you but I dont see how that pertains to my question. The dates have a time value irrespective of how the column is formatted in Access. How did it get in there only on one machine?

Comment: Dates come from the Windows locale, what are the locale settings on the odd PC? After all, 00:00 *is* 12:00 pm or am, depending on how you look at it. `Format: dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn am/pm`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me Remou. We checked the locale settings for the computernand made sure it is the same as hours. Everything was the same, except the problem computer had Windows xp whilst we had Windows 7.

Comment: I am not sure that it is exactly a problem computer, in some ways, the computers that are not displaying a time are the problem because `25-Nov-2011 00:00` includes a time. In fact, I have just realized that there is problem with Access 2010 General Date format, because it does not display midnight as a time.

Comment: Thanks again Remou. Yes, this is a mystery to me. All I know is that with other computers, if I run a query like: SELECT * WHERE myDate >= #14-Nov-2010# AND myDate <= #14-Nov-2010# then the problem computer does not return any data. All others return all records where myDate = #14-Nov-2010#. BTW, the client's IT support have since found problems with the installation of the software on this computer and re-installed it. Waiting to see if the problem was miraculously fixed. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Assuming you have access to both access db's, try running  SELECT cdbl(myDate) against each and see if the actual data is the same.  If so, then could be that the default formats for date time display on the windows 7 machine have been changed, and are carrying into this db either globally or just within Access2010

Comment: Thanks Bill for your suggestion. It may offer some answers. It will take some time to check out, as the client is out of town. I will post back here if we find any answers using your approach. Thanks again for the suggestion.